# PHP is_readable returns false on readable file on apache2

Tags: php, apache2

Cannot migrate old joombla to another server because php cannot read config file. :S

for test reasons I made this code:

```
clearstatcache();
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('configuration2.php')), -4);

if(file_get_contents("configuration.php")) echo " trae conent";
else echo " no trae un joraca ";

if (is_readable('configuration.php')) {
  echo 'The file is readable';
} else {
  echo ' NOOOOO ';
}

readfile('configuration2.php'); 
exit();
```

returns:

> 0no trae un joraca NOOOOO

ls:

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  2189 jun 14 18:16 configuration.php

apache2 runs as www-data:www-data

> www-data 10194  0.0  0.1  25940  3336 ?        S    19:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

.htaccess deleted

Why is the file not readable? I already checked .htaccess, chmod and chown issues.

Comment: Does PHP run as www-data too? That being said, is the path even correct?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct working-dir?

Comment: i found this:
[Sun Jun 12 22:12:12 2016] [warn] [client 1---1] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(configuration.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/ww---/web:/var/w---0/web20/tmp:/var/www/inm--ne.com/web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this:

```
[Sun Jun 12 22:12:12 2016] [warn] [client 1---1] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(configuration.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/ww---/web:/var/w---0/web20/tmp:/var/www/inm--ne.com/web
```

What explains what was the error :D